# android database: convert JSON-encoded PHP result into SQLite-cursor?

Tags: php, mysql, json, sqlite, cursor

My Android app is working with a SQLite database that is stored locally on the device. I now want to switch over to a MySQL database that is running on a web-server.

So far, working with the local database, all data processing of the query results (some ListView visualisation, some calculation stuff)  relies on the cursor object given back by the CursorLoader.

My question is: If I switch to the web database, how do I have to handle the JSON data received from the API in order to get a cursor? Do I simply have to JSON-decode it and then use it as a cursor object? Is this possible? Otherwise I would have to restructure my entire code in order to process the JSON-data instead of a cursor...If possible I would like to avoid that.

So far, the database module of the app is based on an Async CursorLoader that gives a cursor as a result. I use the SQLiteOpenHelper for the database connection and queries.

I have set up a MySQL database on a web server, it will be http-accessed via an API (PHP). The PHP script does all the MySQL-queries via PDO, then JSON-encodes the results and echoes them back to the client.

Comment: json cannot store "code" objects. it's data only. and if you're using a remote mysql db, you're probably doing http requests, which means any cursor your create will be GONE when the http request completes.

Comment: thanks Marc, you are right. Do you know if there is a way to get the data from Json back into a cursor object? Or does a cursor only exist with a database behind (which in my case would be not existant, only on the server....)?

Comment: you could store `limit` offsets and simulate a cursor that way.

Comment: thanks Marc, this might be a way to go, but that seems to be complex....I think the cleanest and correct way is to rewrite all the code and change the loaders from cursor to JSON-arrays. A lot of work for me, but I guess this is the way it has to be.

Comment: yeah, a lot of stuff becomes very hard once you throw http into the mix. you could put an application server into the mix, which could hold open the db connection on android's behalf. but then you're throwing in more stuff and making things even more complicated. if your data set is small enough, just shovel the whole thing across the wire in a json string and do the cursoring in the client.